# How do you link to an image on a page using jQuery Mobile?

Tags: hyperlink, jquery-mobile

I have a page with a normal link to an image. When jQuery Mobile is loaded and you click on the link, all that is returned is 'undefined'.

How can you link to an image and have the image loaded when clicked?

edit:
It's just a normal link with an image:

```
<a href="picture.jpg" class="image"><img src="picture_thumbnail.jpg" /></a>
```

Comment: please edit your question and add some code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work when adding `rel="external"` to the `<a>` tag.

```
<a href="picture.jpg" class="image" rel="external">
  <img src="picture_thumbnail.jpg" />
</a>
```